# Coloring rows before columns in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, paint

I am creating a program which uses a `DataGridView` to edit records in a SQL database. My project manager requires that rows be colored green, yellow, or red depending on whether they've been inserted, updated, or marked for deletion within a time window. He also wants to have the column used to sort the `DataGridView` colored light grey. To handle this, I have created the following event handlers within my form:

```
    private void OnRowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //get the row
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)this.dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row;

        //color the row
        try
        {
            //REDACTED
            //gets booleans used below
            //REDACTED

            if (softDeleted)
                this.dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 213, 91, 95);    //red
            else if (inserted)
                this.dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 83, 223, 146);   //green
            else if (updated)
                this.dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 234, 218, 106);  //yellow
            else
                this.dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty;
        }
        //on failure, abort coloring
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to get data required for coloring - " + ex.Message + ".\n Coloring disabled.");
            Logging.logException(ex);
            this.dataGridView.RowPrePaint -= OnRowPrePaint;
        }
    }
    private void OnSorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //remove color from previous sort column and add to new
        if (this.mLastSortColumnIndex != -1)
        {
            this.dataGridView.Columns[this.mLastSortColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty;
        }
        this.mLastSortColumnIndex = this.dataGridView.SortedColumn.Index;
        this.dataGridView.SortedColumn.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
    }
```

This works wonderfully, and I'm quite happy with it! Or was, until my project manager insisted that the sort color (column coloring) override the row coloring. My attempts have all met with failure - is there any way to pull this off cleanly?

Illustration below - current on left, desired on right.
[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add handler to CellPainting event

```
void OnGridCellPainting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == mLastSortColumnIndex)
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
}
```

this method set LightGray color for cells in sorted column after RowPrePaint

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that event when searching the API for possible fixes... Works like a charm; thank you!